# Image Copy Issue with Ruby File method each_byte

Tags: ruby, image, encoding, unicode, base64

This problem has bugged me for a while.

I have a jpeg file that is 34.6 kilobytes. Let's call it Image A. Using Ruby, when I copy each line of Image A to a newly created file, called Image B, it is copied exactly. It is exactly the same size as Image A and is accessible.

Here is the code I used:

```
image_a = File.open('image_a.jpg', 'r')
image_b = File.open('image_b.jpg', 'w+')

image_a.each_line do |l|
  image_b.write(l)
end

image_a.close
image_b.close
```

This code generates a perfect copy of image_a into image_b.

When I try to copy Image A into Image B, byte by byte, it copies successfully but the file size is 88.9 kilobytes rather than the 34.6 kilobytes. I can't access Image B. My mac system alerted me it may be damaged or is using a file format that isn't recognized.

The related code:

```
//same as before
image_a.each_byte do |b|
  image_b.write(b)
end
//same as before
```

Why is Image B, when copied into byte by byte, larger than Image A? Why is it also damaged in some way, shape, or form? Why is Image A the same size as B, when copied line by line, and accessible?

My guess is the problem is an encoding issue. If so, Why does encoding format matter when copying byte by byte if they translate into the correct code points? Are code points jumbled up into each other so the parser is unable to differentiate between them?

Do \s and \n matter? It seems like it. I did some more research and I found that Image A had 128 lines of code whereas Image B had only one line.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IO#each_byte`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-each_byte) iterates over bytes (aka Integers). [`IO#write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-write), however, takes a string as an argument. So it converts the integer to a string via `to_s`.

Given the first byte in your image is `255`<sup>1</sup>, you'd write the string `"255"` into `image_b`. This is why your `image_b` gets larger. You write number-strings into it.

Try the following when writing back bytes:

```
image_a.each_byte do |l|
  image_b.write l.chr
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As @stefan pointed out jpeg images start with `FF D8`. So the first byte is `255`.

Comment: Or just `image_b.write(l.chr)`

Comment: you are right :) I'll better use `chr()` in my answer. thanks!

Comment: shouldn't each_line be each_byte since chr() is operating on individual bytes? Thanks btw. It worked.

Comment: As @Stefan remarks, `image_b.write(l.chr)` (not `image_b.write(byte.chr)`).

Comment: Thanks, edited. Seems I should not answer when I'm too tired :) Too many typos.

Comment: @tessi JPEGs start with `FF D8`, so the first byte is `255`.